# Simply can't understand why self is not defined

Tags: python, function, class, self

```
import requests

valute = input('Enter currency name: ')

class Rate:
  def __ init__ (self, format_):
    format_ = self.format 

  def name_and_max_value(self, format_='full'):
    """
     Return currency name (‘Name’) with its max value from site
    """
    self.r = requests.get('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js')
    if self.r.json()["Value"] > self.r.json()["Previous"]:
      return self.r.json()["Value"]
    else:
      return self.r.json()["Previous"]

Rate.name_and_max_value(self, format_='full')
```

**Error body:**

Enter currency name: usd

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-4d5dab537669> in <module>()
     17       return self.r.json()["Previous"]
     18 
---> 19 Rate.name_and_max_value(self, format_='full')

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: You did not define `self` outside of the class. You might want to have a look at the [`classes tutorial`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks).

Answer (score 1):

First, you seem to want `name_and_max_value` to be a `classmethod`, since you're not creating an instance. If this is the case you should explicitly say so by using a `@classmethod` decorator. And the convention for these methods is to call the first parameter `cls`, not `self`.

Second, be it a class or an instance method, do not include `self` in your call: that is passed automatically by the system.

Also note that `init_` will never be executed: you probably wanted to write `__init__`?